# SpringBoot: How handle correctly this Linkage Error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, linkageerror

I hope that you can help me..
I have a spring-boot application that loads some jar in a folder (with class and method with annotation `@Test` or `@TestFactory`) and loads in a JSON all jar name-class name-method `Test` name.
When I call a get service `/getTestList` I view this json like this for example:

> {jarFile:{classFileName:{methodTestName1:"xxxx",methodTestName2:"yyy"},{classFileName2:{methodTestName1:"xxxx",methodTestName2:"yyy"} }

This is Controller.class:

```
 @RestController
public class Controller {
public JarClassMethod getAllTests() throws IllegalArgumentException,  NoSuchMethodException, 
InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException,LinkageError, ClassNotFoundException {

    JarClassMethod testClassObjMap= new JarClassMethod();
    LoadLibrary loadLibrary=new LoadLibrary();
    List<JarFile> jarList= loadLibrary.getListJar().stream().map(f -> {
        try {
            return new JarFile(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (JarFile j : jarList) {
        for (Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = j.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            String file = entry.getName();
            if (file.endsWith(".class")) {
                String classname = file.replaceAll("/", ".")
                        .substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("."));
                try {
                    Class<?> currentClass = Class.forName(classname);
                    List<String> testMethods = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < currentClass.getMethods().length; i++) {
                        Method method = currentClass.getMethods()[i];
                        Annotation annTest = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
                        Annotation annTestFactory = method.getAnnotation(TestFactory.class);
                        if (annTest != null || annTestFactory != null) {
                            testMethods.add(method.getName());
                        }
                    }//fine for metodi
                    if (testMethods.size() >=1) {
                        testClassObjMap.put(j.getName().substring(j.getName().lastIndexOf("\\")+1),classname,testMethods);
                        System.out.format("%s %s %s",j.toString(),classname,testMethods);
                    }
                }catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
                    System.out.println("WARNING: failed NoClassDefFoundError " + classname + " from " + file);
                } 
                catch (Throwable e) {
                    System.out.println("WARNING: failed to instantiate " + classname + " from " + file);
                }

            }//if .class
        }//chiudo jarentry for
    }//chiudo jarfile for
    return testClassObjMap;
}

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTestList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<JarClassMethod> getTestList() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    JarClassMethod testClassObjMap=this.getAllTests();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(testClassObjMap, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

with method `getAllTests()` I first load jar like external libraries and after with a for iterate all jarsFile, with another for iterate all classes and finally with another for iterate all method with annotation `@Test` or `@TestFactory`.

On my pc in windows it work correctly but when i package project and put this jar on a Linux Server i have this error:

```
        There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
    loader constraint violation: when resolving method
 "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.ReadOnlyClassToSerializerMap.untypedValueSerializer(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;" the class loader (instance of 
org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader) of the current class, 
com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider, and the class loader (instance of 
sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, 
com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/ReadOnlyClassToSerializerMap, have different Class objects for 
the type com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer used in the signature
```

I tried to exclude Jackson from spring-boot dependency but Response of `getTestList()` doesn't work. The other Jars files used also Jackson libraries.

this is my pom.xml: [pomxml](https://pastebin.com/cXtg83t8)

Pls Help me.. I'm tired from 3 days. :-P
Thanks and

Regards Friends..

Comment: Could you add a full stack trace and point in which line this error exists? Also, show us `JarClassMethod` class.

Comment: When you start the process on the Linux server, are there any jars in the local directory or on the classpath? It looks like a classpath problem to me. Have you checked the version of java? Also, try comparing `java -version` in both environments.